# How do I display a widget on the Android desktop?

Tags: android

in the program TTpod, a feature exists in it when you click the "Display Desktop Lyrics", it has a widget that seems to go over any application I open.  I was wondering how to create a button on the screen that would be displayed over any applications I'd open in the future.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a "floating window" that goes over everything (all apps), spend a minute or two searching with the following keywords.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
```

Be CAREFUL though, these can be cantankerous to implement at best (as I'm finding out), since their implementation varies WIDELY on different devices and APIs!